# Binding multiple targets to same source

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am making a page which contains a `ViewPager` with pages that consist of a `TextView` displaying a title and a `ListView` displaying some charts from a custom view I have made.

I have this working fine in WP7, with the following code:

```xml
<controls:Pivot Title="Stakeholder">
    <controls:PivotItem Header="Last hour">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <chart:MiniChartHour MinMaxRange="{Binding ChartHourRange}" Data="{Binding ChartHourSamples}" Margin="0,0,0,15" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </controls:PivotItem>

    <!--Pivot item last day-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="Last day">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <chart:MiniChartDay MinMaxRange="{Binding ChartDayRange}" Data="{Binding ChartDaySamples}" Margin="0,0,0,15" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </controls:PivotItem>
    ...
    More of these here
    ...
</controls:Pivot>
```

On WP7 however it is using a `Pivot` control, which is similar to the `ViewPager` in android. The `Locations` property is a `ObservableCollection` which holds `LocationViewModel`s. Each of the `LocationViewModel`s have ranges and data for 4 different charts each displaying a different granularity of data. In the code above this `Locations` property is bound several times without any problems. However when I want to do something similar on Android, the `SwissBindings` spew out a lot of warnings about Path is bound more than once. My View code on Android looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/BK.EMS.Stakeholder.UI.Droid.vNext"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/chartHeader"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name"
    />

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxBindableListView 
      android:id="@+id/chartListHour"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
      android:listSelector="#00000000"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/chartdetailhour"
      local:MvxBind="ItemSource Locations, Visibility IsHourVisible,Converter=Visibility"
      />

    <Mvx.MvxBindableListView
      android:id="@+id/chartListDay"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
      android:listSelector="#00000000"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/chartdetailday"
      local:MvxBind="ItemSource Locations, Visibility IsDayVisible,Converter=Visibility"
      />
    ...
    More of the BindableListViews here
    ...
  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The Exceptions I get are:

```
Problem parsing Swiss binding MvxException: You cannot specify Path more than once - first Path 'Locations', second Path 'Visibility IsHourVisible', position 50 in ItemSource Locations, Visibility IsHourVisible,Converter=Visibility
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseNextBindingDescriptionOptionInto (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Interfaces.Parse.MvxSerializableBindingDescription description) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseBindingDescription () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseTargetPropertyNameAndDescription () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.TryParseBindingSpecification (System.String text, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Interfaces.Parse.MvxSerializableBindingSpecification& requestedBindings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use ";" instead of "," to add more than one binding-description.

```
local:MvxBind="ItemSource Locations; Visibility IsDayVisible,Converter=Visibility"
```

should work :-)

Comment: You are right, that is what the problem was. Thanks a bunch! Maybe I should get better glasses 8D